clgetplatformids returns wrong platform count
I have installed the Intel Oneapi under Ubuntu in order to get opencl for Intel integrated graphics.
clinfo shows 4 cl systems on the machine
*paul@paul-HM570:~/src$ clinfo -l
Platform #0: Intel(R) FPGA Emulation Platform for OpenCL(TM)
`-- Device #0: Intel(R) FPGA Emulation Device
Platform #1: Intel(R) OpenCL
`-- Device #0: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3450 @ 1.10GHz
Platform #2: Intel(R) OpenCL
`-- Device #0: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3450 @ 1.10GHz
Platform #3: Intel(R) OpenCL HD Graphics
`-- Device #0: Intel(R) HD Graphics 500 [0x5a85]*
But a call to
err= clGetPlatformIDs(0,NULL,&num_plats);
returns 1 in num_plats
a subsequent call to get a GPU fails with return code -1
err = clGetDeviceIDs(plats[0],   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU  ,   1,       &device_idgputest, &devicecount);
Any clues as to why this may be happening?
The test code was compiled with gcc using the intel library for opencl thus
gcc  -o gpuprobe   gpuprobe.c    -lintelocl
I only got one cl platform reported when clinfo shows 4
